# How to compare nested hashes

Tags: perl, hash

I'm trying to compare data in hash in order to find differences.
My hash:

```
$VAR1 = {
10.200.40.10 => {
                5678903  => { 
                                'status' => 'ACTIVE',
                                'age'    => '20'
                            }
                8234234  => {
                                'status' => 'NOT ACTIVE',
                                'age'    => '23'
                            }
                }        
10.200.40.11 => {        
                5678903  => { 
                                'status' => 'NOT ACTIVE',
                                'age'    => '20'
                            }
                8234234  => {
                                'status' => 'NOT ACTIVE',
                                'age'    => '23'
                            }
                }        
10.200.40.12 => {        
                5678903  => { 
                                'status' => 'NOT ACTIVE',
                                'age'    => '21'
                            }
                8234234  => {
                                'status' => 'ACTIVE',
                                'age'    => '23'
                            }
                }
}
```

I would like to check if the same user e.g with ID 5678903 has the same values of status and age on each server. Should I divide it for three separated hashes?

Thanks for all suggestions!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Here is an example how you can compare the values for a given user in the sub hashes. Assuming your hash is called `$info`:

```
use List::Util qw(uniq);

my $info = { ... };  # Set up the hash here
my $user = "5678903";
my $status = get_user_value( $info, 'status', $user );
my $age = get_user_value( $info, 'age', $user );

if ( ((uniq @$status) == 1) && ((uniq @$age) == 1) ) {
    say "Same status and age";
}
else {
    say "Not same status and age";
}

sub get_user_value {
    my ( $info, $key, $user ) = @_;

    my @values;
    for my $server (keys %$info) {
        if (exists $info->{$server}{$user}) {
            push @values, $info->{$server}{$user}{$key}
              if exists $info->{$server}{$user}{$key};
        }
    }
    return \@values;
}
```